# Microsoft Access: Using other fields in an Autonumber

Tags: ms-access, format, number-formatting, fields

I'm trying to use Microsoft Access to start an employee database. However, I want the display of the Employee ID to be the initials and then their number. For example, John Smith with the ID 0002 is JS0002. I've been playing around with format but it doesn't seem I can do this if I put my EmployeeID as an autonumber. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *However, I want the display of the Employee ID to be the initials and then their number.* Pay attention - you tell "to display", not "to store" - and you are intuitively correct! Store as-is - clear number, construct the view described during data retrieve using according expression.

Comment: I reccomend that you avoid concatenated keys, or add any meaning to them. Sally Smith might get married and change her name to Sally Bloggs. So do you now have to change her Employee id to SB0003?

Comment: Id start with an autonumber at like 10100

Answer (score 0):

You control the way fields are displayed with the `Format` property. If you apply the format to the field in the table then it applies to all views of all records. You can't apply a different format to each record.

If you want to display their initials before the employee number then you need to build that in to a query.

This takes the first character from the left of each name component and combines it with a formatted number.

```
SELECT Left([FirstName],1) & Left([LastName],1) & Format(ID,"0000") AS EmployeeID
FROM Employees;
```

In my testing the result is exactly what you want. You can include this query in any form or report where this format is required. You can also include this as just part of a larger query to base your forms and reports off of.